# Angular 2 templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I want to utilize Angular2 with ASP.NET MVC (not core). My goal is to generate UI on the server side. I have a model and I can generate a markup base on it.

I have couple of Angular2 components:

```
//1
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<h1>Angular</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent {}

//2
@Component({
selector: 'my-text',
template: `<div><input type="text" placeholder="default"/></div>`
})
export class MyTextComponent {}
```

I generating markup with MVC (razor engine) to something like this:

```
   <my-app>
   <my-text> </my-text>
   <my-text> </my-text>
   <my-text> </my-text>
   ...
   <my-text> </my-text>
</my-app>
```

Unfortunately when angular application started my markup transforms in to

```
<my-app><h1>Angular</h1></my-app>
```

When I add markup in to AppComponent template, like this:

```
   template: `<h1>Angular</h1> 
   <my-text> </my-text>
   <my-text> </my-text>
   <my-text> </my-text>
   ...
   <my-text> </my-text>`
```

everything works fine -  selectors are processed by angular.
Why does this happend, and how to utilize MVC markup? I expected that angular2 recieved markup MVC and processed it.

Comment: The markup you posted is invalid. The closing tags miss the `/`.

Comment: Ok. It is my fault when I created this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Angular2 bootstraps the root component it applies the component to the element matching its selector. The content of the target element is purged.

Angular2 doesn't support transclusion on the root element.

As far as I remember there is something with ngDowngrade or ngUpgrade that might allow it but I don't know about that.

Angular2 also does **not** process any bindings added to the root element for security reasons (`<my-app [someProp]="xxx" (click)="doSomethign()"></my-app>`).

Comment: So, is there another path to go through to reach my goal?

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal exactly is. You want to transclude content from the index.html to the root component? I don't know of a way and `ngUpgrade`, `ngDowngrade` seem like hacks for this case. They are for temporary use during migration from Angular 1.x to Angular2.

Comment: My goal is to generate UI on the server side. I have a model and I can generate a markup base on it

Comment: You can create a component and load it's template from the server. I don't know details about this because I haven't tried creating components this way myself yet but there are several questions with answers about this.